# WIA services 2, download and install on windows xp / 7

Tags: wia

I've written a application that scans images from a scanner.
this works fine on my development machine (win7 ultimate sp1 64bit).

i've tried to run the app on a windows xp machine (or windows server 2008 standard) and it failed with this error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {E1C5D730-7E97-4D8A-9E42-BBAE87C2059F} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

it seems that the machines are missing the WIA dlls.

when looking around microsoft site for the installation files, i've failed to find them.

so my question are, 
where can i find the installation files ? 
and can i install WIA 2 on XP?

OrenL

Answer (score 0):

The error message means the control is not installed properly on the machine (your windows xp and windows server 2008).

Are you developing a control to implement the image scanning feature? If yes, you need to register the dll file you've created on the client machine, not the WIA dll.

Comment: but i don't have any dll. i've developed a application (*.exe)
the CLSID in the error is looking for '@%SystemRoot%\system32\wiaaut.dll,-3001'
  which is one of the dlls in the WIA service