# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E1C5D730-7E97-4D8A-9E42-BBAE87C2059F}

Tags: c#, wia

I have developed a window application using c# in windows 7.
My application is scanning the images from the scanner and showing it on picture box.
It is working fine on my machine. 
I have created the package and installed it on client's system who is using windows XP and when I click on my scanner form the following error occurs:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E1C5D730-7E97-4D8A-9E42-BBAE87C2059F} failed due to the following error: 80040154
```

I am totally unable to find any help on internet. Does anyone have any solution?
I am scanning images via WIA dll.

Comment: There was a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049092/wia-services-2-download-and-install-on-windows-xp-7] you might want to look at.

Comment: I have already checked it. But there is no satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it finally.

http://vbnet.mvps.org/files/updates/wiaautsdk.zip

download it and follow the instructions.

Comment: The readme file says that you need to register the dll. That's exactly what I told you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a com component that you're using that needs to be registered.

Comment: but how i can register it?

Comment: but where i can type this?

Comment: I have type regsvr32 Interop.WIA.dll. But it says not found.